# MySql random select and delete in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT u.name AS nume, p.premiu AS premiu
FROM fbusers AS u, premii AS p
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
```

What I want is to select a random user for giving a prize and afterwards I want to delete that prize from prize's table.
It is possible to do it in the same query? How should I proceed?

EDIT:The logic is to display the winner and the prize and if possible to insert the result in other table and afterwards to delete the prize from the table for not being possible for somebody else to win the same prize.

Comment: If these two queries are always logically together, you could just wrap them in a stored procedure.

Comment: Is the prize also random, or do you allocate them (to random users) in a defined order?

Comment: The prize is also random, I'm putting all the prizes in a table and it will be a random select(user and prize).

Comment: I would also look into doing a "soft" delete so you can keep the prize information for statistical reporting.  A soft delete is merely a status column with one char; typically an A, I, or D (Active, Inactive or Deleted).  You can then query the table for any prize, past or present, regardless of who won it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: you can't do SELECT, INSERT and DELETE in one query. Use transactions if you want all these three operations to be treated atomically (i.e. they will all be executed, or if any one fails, the others will be rolled back)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can but I don't see logic here because no info about who won left:

```
DELETE price FROM price 
    JOIN (SELECT u.name AS nume, p.premiu AS premiu
    FROM fbusers AS u, premii AS p
    ORDER BY RAND( ) 
    LIMIT 1) a
ON price.premiu = a.premiu
```

Comment: Thanks, it's my fault, I didn't explained well. The logic is to display the winner and the prize and if possible to insert the result in other table and afterwards to delete the prize from the table for not being possible for somebody else to win the same prize.